# Why would I use env before a command?

Tags: bash, shell

I have seen colleagues prefix (interactive) shell commands with `env`, such as `env KEY=value my_script` to invoke `my_script`.

My question is: what's the point of using `env` here? Why wouldn't you just write `KEY=value my_script`?

I understand what `env` does, and use cases such as `#!/usr/bin/env python` make perfect sense. But, I do not understand why you would prefix `env` to commands in an interactive shell.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's probably no good reason why you'd *have* to use `env` in an interactive command.

In a Bourne-derived shell (sh, ksh, bash, zsh), these two commands:

```
key=VALUE my_script
env key=VALUE my_script
```

are essentially identical.

The difference is that in the first command, `key=Value` is part of the shell's syntax, not part of the command that's executed. `env` is an actual command (it's typically not built into the shell). Because of that, there are contexts where you need to use `env`, for example if you're running a command that invokes another command. For example, if you're  using `find` with the `-exec` option:

```
find . -type f -exec some_command \;
```

then `some_command` is invoked by `find`, not by the shell, and a leading `key=VALUE` won't be recognized. You can use `env` to work around that.

That's a fairly unusual situation, though, and it doesn't apply to running a simple command.

Another possible reason is that the csh and tcsh shells (which are not derived from the Bourne shell) don't use the same syntax. Someone who's accustomed to using csh or tcsh interactively might use `env key=Value my_script` out of habit.

Or someone might feel that using the `env` command is more explicit and therefore clearer.

At worst, it's a harmless quirk. It does invoke an additional process and is probably slightly less efficient, but in an interactive command that doesn't really matter.

And as chepner's comment points out the `env` command lets you set environment variables with names that aren't valid shell variable names (though that's rarely a good idea), and the `-i` option lets you clear the existing environment before setting variables.

(As for the `#!/usr/bin/env` hack, see [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/29608/10454) and [my answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/29620/10454) for a discussion.)

Comment: `env` allows you to add names to the environment that aren't valid shell identifiers, e.g., `env "weird name"=foo bash`. It also provides a way to *remove* names from the child's environment by using the `-i` flag to start with an empty environment, containing only the name/value pairs passed as arguments to `env`.